# Space Complexity with no variables defined

Tags: python, time-complexity, list-comprehension, nested-lists, space-complexity

Suppose I had some code:

```py
def foo(forest: list[list[int]]) -> int:
    return sum([1 for tree in forest for leaf in tree])
```

In this code, no variables are defined. Everything is evaluated in one line, which means to my knowledge the data isn't being stored anywhere. Does that mean this program has a space complexity of O(1)?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The list comprehension `[1 for ...]` might contain many items, so it certainly isn't O(1).  Granted, that comprehension isn't saved anywhere, but it will take up memory, however briefly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, what is the *n* here?

I think there are two different variables of importance here, I'll call them `M = len(forest)` and `K = max(len(tree) for tree in forest)`.

Then the time complexity would be O(MK).

Next, the list you are constructing has a length of O(MK), so its space complexity is the same as the time complexity.

You can avoid that by using a generator expression instead of a list comprehension, like so:

```
return sum(1 for tree in forest for leaf in tree if leaf < 0)
```

This avoids having to store every value, only generating a single value at a time when calculating the sum, so its additional space complexity would be O(1).